# How to make a null char?

Tags: c++, c++14

Just working through c++ primer book. Things are going smoothy, however, when using a range for in order to replace all punctuation with null char's, they are replaced with a space (' ') instead.
I cant understand why :/
How do I change this so that punctuation is replace with no character, rather than a space?

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

int main()
{
    string s1("Hi I'm Greg.");

    cout << s1 << endl;

    for(char &c : s1){
        if(ispunct(c)){
            c = '\0';
        }
    }

    cout << s1 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Sorry if its a dumb question...
Cheers!

edit:
Compiled in c++14
Here is my output:

> Hi I m Greg

Comment: when I [run it](http://ideone.com/cHdlit) it just does what you want

Comment: btw you should include the output you get and the output you expect in the question

Comment: You make a null character by using '\0', or 0x00 or 0.

Comment: What version of C++ are you using ?

Comment: BTW, if your string has multiple punctuation symbols, you will be placing a nul at each punctuation.  Try this string "Now the election, is over, I will leave.  Next I will eat.".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A NUL character is, first and foremost, a *character*. It isn't nothing; it's a NUL character. That is, the string "some\0thing" is *not* the same thing as "something". Your particular console renders the "\0" character as a space, but a different console can render it as nothing. But that doesn't change the fact that a NUL character is not nothing.

If you want to *remove* a character, then what you have to do is shift all of the following characters down.

Comment: Thanks, had no knowledge that NUL characters can be rendered differently, varying depending on the machine. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 3):

The null character is not a printable character. Hence, you don't see anything in the console for the null characters that are written to `cin`.